# Дополнения гостевой ОС для ALT Linus 6.0 под Virtualbox

Tags: altlinux, virtualbox, linux

Как их установить? Хотелось бы увидеть воспроизводимый алгоритм, доступный тем, кто не является гуру линукса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ставим дополнения в Linux-то делаем так.

1.Вариант-ставим из репозиториев(В каждом дистре-свои методы и пакетные менеджеры)

2.Ставим из образа

Переходим в режим суперпользователя

```
# su -# mount -o loop /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso /mnt# cd mnt# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Образ должен уже быть в системе.Обычно складывается по пути /usr/share/virtualbox/.Если нет-значит нужно поставить пакет содержащий его.

Ну или читать  http://www.lintest.ru/wiki/Virtual_Box_%28ALT_Linux%29

Answer (score 1):

Для архива: http://altlinux.org/Virtualbox =>

```
apt-get install kernel-modules-virtualbox-addition-std-def  virtualbox-guest-additions
```